# Custom Post Type archive giving 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I am using WAMP with the latest version of WordPress installed.  I have a custom post type created using the following...

```
function register_fruit() {
register_post_type('fruit', array(
'labels' => array(
'name' => __( 'Fruit' ),
),
'public' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'rewrite' => array("slug" => "/fruit", "with_front" => false),
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') // this is IMPORTANT
));
}
add_action('init', 'register_fruit', 0 );
```

This works fine when viewing individual items for example..

```
www.mydomain.com/fruit/apple
www.mydomain.com/fruit/orange
www.mydomain.com/fruit/pear
```

But if I try and view the archive pages such as...

```
www.mydomain.com/fruit
```

I get a 404,  I can't see where the problem lies, can anyone help?

Comment: make sure you have 'has_archive' => true when you're registering your post type.

Comment: Has this ever been solved? By one of the answers (then accept) or in another way (then describe and accept yourself). I'm having the same issue, there is various same/similar on StackExchange/StackOverflow and elsewhere online, none of those suggestions have helped...

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried refreshing permalinks?
Settings -> Permalinks (don't have to change anything)
Then try again?

Comment: Yep tried that, still nothing

Comment: FFS - Keep forgetting that!

Answer (score 4):

Remove the leading slash in your rewrite argument, This:

```
'rewrite' => array("slug" => "/fruit", "with_front" => false),
```

should be:

```
'rewrite' => array("slug" => "fruit", "with_front" => false),
```

and your archive will work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and tried all the solutions (flush permalinks, various rewrites, etc) until I stumbled in the WP Codex on

> **query_var**
>       (boolean or string) (optional) False to disable the query_var, set as string to use custom query_var instead of default which is $taxonomy, the taxonomy's "name". True is not seen as a valid entry and will result in 404 issues.

Indeed, I had `'query_var' => true` which caused my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue using:

```
function cp_init_types() {
register_post_type( 'nursing-home',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Nursing Homes' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Nursing Home' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        /*'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'nursing-homes', 'with_front' => true ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search'=> false,
        'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag'),*/
    )
);
/*register_taxonomy('location','nursing-home',[
        'labels' => [
            'name' => __('Locations'),
            'singular_name' => __('Location')
        ],
        'public' => true
    ]);*/
}

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
if ( is_post_type_archive( "nursing-home" ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set('type',"nursing-home");
    $test = $query->get('type');
    var_dump($test);
}

return $query;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
add_action("init", "cp_init_types");
```

I added the "pre_get_posts" action because I was having the same problem as fightstar.

Comment: And does that `pre_get_posts` addition solve the problem? If not, this is not an answer and should not have been posts as one.